# Installing the diesel client in rust throws error

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to follow the '[Getting Started](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started)' tutorial of diesel, but when trying to install the diesel client

```
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

I get the following error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
= note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `diesel_cli` due to previous error
error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v2.0.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installuQxuuj`
```

In the getting started document they say, that a database library client has to be installed. But from the examples I found it looks like I just need to add them to the Cargo.toml file.

Comment: The getting started document doesn't say how to install the database client library because instructions to do so are different for each database and system target. Likely either `apt install libpq-dev` or `brew install libpq`.

Comment: this worked, thx. if you want you can post this as an asnwer, so i can accept it as correct